# Discrepancy between Google My Business and Google Analytics Sessions Data

Tags: google-analytics, visitors, session, google-my-business

I am seeing my Google my business page website visits as - 4,412 while in google analytics sessions - 8,000 for same month (1 month data). We are using utm parameters to capture GMB listings clicks in analytics account. Any idea why is there so much difference between this data.

Comment: It's Google. ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: Google can't count: http://searchengineland.com/why-google-cant-count-results-properly-53559